# Is the use of different prepositions in this sentence interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions

Can I use whichever proposition I want in this sentence? Or is there one that is better suited to use than the others and if so, why?

> A. I have waited for two hours **past** my appointment time.
>
> B. I have waited for two hours **from** my appointment time.
>
> C. I have waited for two hours **since** my appointment time.
>
> D. I have waited for two hours **after** my appointment time.

Comment: You can use anything you want *depending on what you mean*. They all carry different connotations.

Comment: I am surprised to learn that those prepositions in this sentence could imply different meanings. I thought surely they all mean the same thing. Could you please tell me what each implies?

Comment: Not as strong as "meanings" ... they all mean *roughly* the same thing, but you'd use them to express varying states of annoyance. For example, D is stronger than B, and would be used to express a certain outrage. A is also stronger than B, but not as strong as D. C is milder still, and a little strange-sounding. And while it is possible to use B to protest, it's use would be odd with the setup provided.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. So those prepositions are interchangeable and the choice to use one of them is primarily based on how annoyed you are.

Answer (score -1):

None of these is really how I would use those prepositions.  Others might think they're fine.  Here are what I think are more natural versions:

1. > It's now **two hours past my appointment time** that I've been waiting.
2. > I had to wait for two hours for my appointment, **from 2 until 4 pm**.
3. > It's been **two hours since my appointment time**, and I've been waiting all that time.
4. > It's now **two hours after my appointment time**, and I've been waiting.

They all mean more or less the same thing, but the usage is different because they imply different relationships with the appointment time.  Here's a different set of examples:

> It is **past** sundown.
>
> It is **after** sundown.
>
> It's been a while **since** the sun went down.
>
> It's now three hours **from** the time the sun went down.

I guess the short answer is that you should not think of these as interchangeable but instead learn the patterns where each applies.

Comment: Both A. and C. seem idiomatic to me; without context, it's impossible to say they aren't.